# scrapy spider scraping data from link randomly why?

Tags: python, scrapy

First i have grabed all the coin link from the website and requested to those link.
But scrapy do'nt requesting serially from the link list.after requesting to thos link scraping data successfully but when saving to csv file it making a blank row every time after one succesfull scraped item.[Result Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeesF.png)
I am expecting that it will request serially from the  link list and it will not make any blank row.how can i do that?

I am using python 3.6 and scrapy version 1.5.1

My code:

```
import scrapy


class MarketSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'market'
    allowed_domains = ['coinmarketcap.com']
    start_urls = ['http://coinmarketcap.com/']
    def parse(self, response):
        Coin = response.xpath('//*[@class="currency-name-container link-secondary"]/@href').extract()
        for link in Coin:
            absolute_url = response.urljoin(link)
            yield scrapy.Request(absolute_url,callback=self.website_link)
    def website_link(self,response):
        link = response.xpath('//*[@class="list-unstyled details-panel-item--links"]/li[2]/a/@href').extract()
        name = response.xpath('normalize-space(//h1)').extract()
        yield{'Name': name ,'Link': link}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think scrapy is visiting pages in a multi-threaded (producer/consumer) fashion. This can explain the non-sequential aspect of your result.
To verify this hypothesis, you could change your config to use a single thread.

For the blank link, are you sure any of your name or link variable contains a \n ?

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy is an asynchronous framework - multiple requests are executed concurrently and the responses are parsed as they are received.

The only way to reliably control which responses are parsed first is to turn this feature off, e.g. by setting [CONCURRENT_REQUESTS](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests) to 1.
This would make your spider less efficient though, and this kind of control of the parse order is rarely necessary, so I would avoid it if possible.

The extra newlines in csv exports on windows are a known issue, and will be fixed in the next scrapy release.

Comment: but when grabing link list, it scraping list serially not randomly why?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you elaborate?

Comment: entered the link and grabeb link: 
    '/currencies/bitcoin/', '/currencies/ripple/', '/currencies/ethereum/', '/currencies/stellar/', '/currencies/bitcoin-cash/',' as website where 1 : bitcoin 2: ripple 3: ethereum 4:steller

Comment: the link i am grabing is ok and its serial by serial as website but when i entering to the grabing link why not serially ... you can see the csv file where first ,second,third coin info is not same as the website listed.

Comment: My answer addresses this - requests are created at the same time, responses are parsed when received. How long a request takes depends on a number of variables, there is no way to know which response will be received first.

Comment: hmm understood tnx